# openpyxl: checksum mismatch between files, same seed data though

Tags: python, md5, openpyxl, xlsx, checksum

I have created an **Excel** file using [**`openpyxl`**](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library. Then, I decided to get the checksum of the generated file. I have used *md5* and it returns the hash value (say **`XYZ`**). So far so good
After that, I **re-generated the file** again, but this time I have got a hash value which is not **`XYZ`**. I have used the same seed data to generate the files and the script returns different hash values each time.

Why this is happening?

**Environment**

- Python==3.6
- openpyxl==3.0.3

#### minimal verifiable example

```
import datetime
import hashlib
from openpyxl import Workbook


def get_file_hash(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as file_to_hash:
        return hashlib.md5(file_to_hash.read()).hexdigest()


work_book = Workbook()
work_sheet = work_book.active
sample_data = [{'name': 'Matthew Morales',
                'address': '3539 Knight Plaza\nSmithland, OR 76492',
                'zipcode': '85464',
                'num': 0,
                'datetime': datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 24, 15, 33, 54),
                'float': 0.12,
                'bool': True},
               {'name': 'Jack Jones',
                'address': 'Unit 7284 Box 4842\nDPO AE 66772',
                'zipcode': '08425',
                'num': 1,
                'datetime': datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 24, 15, 33, 54),
                'float': 1.12,
                'bool': True},
               {'name': 'Jennifer Higgins',
                'address': 'Unit 6492 Box 6602\nDPO AP 86505',
                'zipcode': '72306',
                'num': 2,
                'datetime': datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 24, 15, 33, 54),
                'float': 2.12,
                'bool': True},
               ]

field_names = list(sample_data[0])
for column_index, field_name in enumerate(field_names, 1):  # writing header
    work_sheet.cell(1, column_index, field_name)
for row_index, data in enumerate(sample_data, 2):
    for column_index, field_name, in enumerate(data, 1):
        work_sheet.cell(row_index, column_index, data[field_name])

mve_file_name = 'mve_xlsx_file.xlsx'
work_book.save(mve_file_name)
print(get_file_hash(mve_file_name))
```

Comment: File metadata includes things like a timestamp so comparing checksums like this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

the .xlsx format is really just a zip file of the Excel workbook contents... mostly represented in XML files. You can actually use `zip` to extract all those files.

Independent of the data content is some metadata which includes a timestamp (for me, it was in a file called `.\docProps\core.xml`). The timestamp will be different each time the file is created, even though the *data* used to create each file was the same. So, the MD5 hashes from a binary read of the files will never match.